# App work in console, not as windows service

Tags: c#, com

I have an app using COM library. When i run it to test in console app it works good. But when i install it as Windows Service using installutil. In logs i have error

```
Message: (SaveInvoice) - Zapisywanie faktury - FS/12584/2012/01
 Nie znaleziono błedu o kodzie: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {F8605331-7454-4A45-98DB-A69EBB3D2947} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8000ffff Katastrofalny błąd. (0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)).           
Stacktrace: SaveDocuments.SaveInputDocuments => SaveMethods.SaveInvoice => LogProvider.ErrorException           
Exception: 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {F8605331-7454-4A45-98DB-A69EBB3D2947} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8000ffff Katastrofalny błąd. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)).
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Rewizor.Application.Start.get_Gt()
   at Rewizor.Application.Start.get_Rewizor()
   at Rewizor.Parsers.Invoice.InvoiceParser.InvoiceParserVatDocument(CustEDIInvoice invoice)
   at Rewizor.ModelRepository.Invoice.InvoiceRepository.CreateInvoice(CustEDIInvoice invoice)
   at DALRewizor.RewizorRepository.CreateInvoice(CustEDIInvoice invoice)
   at EDIService.BLL.RepositoryBLL.CreateInvoice(CustEDIInvoice invoice)
   at BLL.InboxRepository.SaveMethods.SaveInvoice(EDI_OutputStorage item)
```

Anyone have idea, how to solve it?

Comment: Are you certain that the account running the service has access to the necessary dll(s)?

Comment: You should check the user rights, try running it as `network service` / `local system`

Comment: It's run by default as local system. When i run it as network service, i receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

One of the common problems in this scenario are user permissions, because the service runs as a different user than that who runs in console. But judging by the comments on the question, you already checked it.

Another source of errors is the fact that the working directory of the console application is the directory where the EXE is located. With Windows Services, it's not; the working directory is `C:\Windows\System32` (or wherever `%SYSTEMDIR%` is). So, if you have code that relies on the current working directory (such as reading a file in the same directory), it will not work as a service. I'm not sure, but maybe the same problem could happen if you are trying to load a COM library in the same path as the EXE.

So, what I suggest you:

- Double check your permissions.
- Check any code that relies on relative paths and change it to absolute paths instead.

Comment: The path in dll properties is `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Interop.InsERT\1.170.0.0__a59bfa3a209beb60\Interop.InsERT.dll`, so I think the path is good. I try to start service with roles :netowrk, local system, local service, but it still don't work